# How did designer apply this css class?

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-server-side, matblazor

I am using the MatBlazor component library: https://www.matblazor.com/

and I am trying to understand how the designer for this website: https://blazor-wasm.quarella.net/Account/Login

centered the `<MatCard/>`  element like so:
[image]

My following code looks like this:

```
@page "/login"

@using System.Text.Json;
@using Data.Models
@using MatBlazor 

@inject HttpClient Http
    <MatCard >
        <MatCardContent >

        <MatH2>Login</MatH2>

        <button @onclick="OnLoginClick">Log in</button>

        <p>Need an account? Sign up</p>

        <button @onclick="OnSignUp">Sign up</button>
        </MatCardContent>
    </MatCard>

@code {

}
```

which outputs:
[image]

The example code provided here: [Login Razor Page](https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate/blob/d2578d1402fc24deefab69e9fa80afe52e63736f/src/Shared/Modules/BlazorBoilerplate.Theme.Material/Pages/Account/Login.razor), specifically [line 27](https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate/blob/d2578d1402fc24deefab69e9fa80afe52e63736f/src/Shared/Modules/BlazorBoilerplate.Theme.Material/Pages/Account/Login.razor#L27) `{<MatCard>` doesn't have any classes but the element is centered nicely across the screen.

Two questions

1. How do I achieve this card centering effect using the MatBlazor library (minimal custom css)?
2. How the login page designer center it? I see there was a ".login-container" class added which is [here](https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate/blob/281db6bb94993712472d913ff3d1c2f5bbd2a2f6/src/Shared/Modules/BlazorBoilerplate.Theme.Material/wwwroot/css/site.css) but there's no indication of it being used in the razor page.

EDIT:

3. Where did the designer use `class="login-body"` or `class="login-container"` based on the answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As you mention, if you inspect the element of the login page, you can see that the MatCard is using the class `login-container` which applies a margin `auto` to the left and right side of the element.  That's what is causing it to be centered.

[image: Login Container css]

2. Most likely, per the stylesheet you referenced, the wrapping elements on the login page reference the CSS located [here](https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate/blob/281db6bb94993712472d913ff3d1c2f5bbd2a2f6/src/Shared/Modules/BlazorBoilerplate.Theme.Material/wwwroot/css/site.css#L129).  It's called `.login-body` and just like in item 1 above, it is using a margin of `auto` to center horizontally.
3. The `login-body` and `login-container` classes are applied to the pages by either the Shared/Components or the Shared/Layouts.  For example, the Login page you reference in your question appears to be using the `LoginLayout.razor` [here](https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate/blob/281db6bb94993712472d913ff3d1c2f5bbd2a2f6/src/Shared/Modules/BlazorBoilerplate.Theme.Material/Shared/Layouts/LoginLayout.razor).  There you can see that both of these classes are being used.

Comment: Is it a custom class that is used in this specific project or can `login-body` be found in the Matblazor library? My biggest misunderstand is that they dont **use** `login-body` explicitly in the code, or at least, i'm just not seeing it. Can you please edit your answer to includw here `login-body` is being used?